# How can I have clickable text in the AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, appbar

I am aware that I can use IconButton in the actions of the AppBar in Flutter. But instead of the icon, I'd like the user to see the words 'Save' or 'Back' or 'Cancel' and click on them in the AppBar. How can I achieve this?  Here is part of my code that shows the AppBar. Instead of the save Icon, I'd like to use 'Save'

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      tooltip: "Cancel and Return to List",
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context, true);
      },
    ),
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Text(title),
      actions: <Widget>[

        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.save),
          tooltip: "Save Todo and Retrun to List",
          onPressed: () {
            save();
          },
        )
      ],
    ),//AppBar
```

Comment: You can Use FlatButton.icon(onPressed: (){save();}, icon: Icon(Icons.save), label: 'Save'); Instead of Iconbutton.

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed a flat button actually.

Comment: But it didn't work for the arrow_back

Comment: to be exact: there is not enough space for word 'cancel' in the leading section instead of the arrow_back

Comment: For those who want an icon instead of text, see [How to add icon to AppBar in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941227/how-to-add-icon-to-appbar-in-flutter)

Comment: **ElevatedButton** will workout instead of TextButton or IconButton to display text with click action in Appbar's actions menu

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `FlatButton` within an `AppBar`'s `actions` list:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("Test Screen"),
  actions: <Widget>[
    FlatButton(
      textColor: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text("Save"),
      shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
    ),
  ],
),
```

`onPressed` must be defined or the button will appear disabled.
Also note that by default the shape of the button will create a filled rectangle for the InkWell effect. By setting the `shape` property to `CircleBorder`, we get a nicer effect for the pressed state.

E.g.

Not pressed:

[image]

Pressed:

[image]

Comment: FlatButton() has been replaced by TextButton() [docs] (https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#:~:text=The%20FlatButton%2C%20RaisedButton%20and%20OutlineButton%20widgets%20have%20been%20replaced%20by%20TextButton%2C%20ElevatedButton%2C%20and%20OutlinedButton%20respectively.)

Answer (score 12):

Use **`TextButton`**:

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
  actions: <Widget>[
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Save'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Dont use that way because you'll have to add style to fix the possition

Comment: @TuGordoBello Updated the code. Thanks for pointing out, I didn't realise I was using a plain old approach back then.

Comment: Has no effect on 1.22 version

Comment: @EricYuan If I'm not wrong `TextButton` was added in Flutter 2.0 onwards.

Answer (score 5):

If you have short string then you can pass `Text` widget in place of `Icon` into the `IconButton.icon` argument:

```dart
IconButton(
  icon: Text(
    "Save",
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.apply(
      color: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.actionsIconTheme.color,
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: _save,
),
```

Unfortunately, it will not work for a longer text like *Cancel*.

Comment: This works but you have to change the icon size.

IconButton(
   iconSize: 50,
   icon: Text("DONE"),
),

Comment: Agreed. By default it will work for most single letters (e.g. R, S) but not for longer ones like 'm'.

Answer (score 5):

It's the second time I come to this thread to find a solution. I actually had upvoted a few answers that I found interesting.

@sosite solution's is almost perfect and changing the `iconSize` allows to display longer texts. But, it's not perfect because the button's splash radius will be too large.

The best approach is using the `constraints: BoxConstraints(width: ...)`. It will mimic the default IconButton's splash radius.

We can use bigger texts, multi-world texts and align the text to the center to be perfectly aligned.

```
IconButton(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 80),
            icon: Text('CREATE GAME', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
```

If the text is cut, increase the width value :)

[image]

Comment: Perfect---------

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use `Center` to wrap your control and give it a little space to the right when the control is the most right one. Whatever is inside is not important.

```
AppBar(
      title: Text('The tile'),
      actions: [Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,8,0),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){},
            child: Text(
              'Send',
              textScaleFactor: 1.5,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )],
    ),
```

Answer (score -3):

Use new version **Flutter 2.0**

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text(""),
  actions: <Widget>[
    TextButton(
      textColor: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(""),
      shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: )),
    ),
  ],
),
```