# How to add icon to AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, icons, flutter-appbar

If I have an AppBar like this:

[image]

How do I add a clickable icon to it like this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I have clickable text in the AppBar in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713583/how-can-i-have-clickable-text-in-the-appbar-in-flutter)

Comment: Doesn't matter. Same principle. You can wrap Icon in a flat button or `InkWell` and have the same effect. I thought there was a lack of trying to find resources and experimenting when there were similar resources regarding making actions clickable in Appbar.

Comment: `actions` is list of widgets - doesn't matter what widget you put into - icon or text

Answer (score 167, accepted):

[image]

You can add an icon to the AppBar by adding an IconButton widget to the `actions` list of the AppBar.

```
AppBar(
  title: Text('My App'),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.settings,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        // do something
      },
    )
  ],
),
```

### See also

- [AppBar Basics documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/basic-app-bar)
- [How can I have clickable text in the AppBar in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713583/how-can-i-have-clickable-text-in-the-appbar-in-flutter)

Comment: what if you want the icon to be on the left side?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL, You can use the `leading` parameter of `AppBar` to add a widget (including an icon) to the left side.

Answer (score 47):

[image]

Use `leading` for left sided icon and `actions` for right sided.

```dart
AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  title: Text('AppBar'),
  leading: IconButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
  ),
  actions: [
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.call),
    ),
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Leading icon is not visible.

Comment: @BoraKeçeci Please share a minimal reproducible code via Dartpad.